# Sqoop import --validate log the row count validation results

Tags: sqoop2, sqoop

sqoop import --connect abc.com --table test --validate

On Executing above import statement,

Where does sqoop import --validate log the row count validation results ?

In logs folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see the validation results in the logs.